# How to change package view in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I change the package view like:

[image: with dot] to:

[image: withou dot]

in IntelliJ 12.1.4?

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 new UI, press `ctrl/cmd + shift + a`, search for `Project View Options`. From `Tree Appearance`, check `Compact Middle Packages`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Click on the gear icon at the top right on the package view, and make sure that "Flatten Packages" and "Compact empty middle packages" are unchecked.

Answer (score 14):

This screen shot taken from IntelliJ IDEA 2017. Most of the time the answer will be same on every Intellij IDE. 
As JB mentioned this should solve your problem. This screen shot will help a beginner find it easily.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 2017 none flatten packages]

Answer (score 2):

Since they updated their UI, this is where you can expect to find it in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.

[image: Screenshot showing IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1]

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij click on the gear icon on the left side of the window, select Tree Appearence and then Flatten Packages and Compact Middle Packages.