# Eclipse to IntelliJ transfer

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have copied my src package structure from eclipse to intellij and it makes this structure within src folder:

[image]

How do I make it dz1.drugi so I can one click expand all to my classes?

Another question is how to select default project folder as it is "workspace" at \Users\{Name} for eclipse. Right now, when I create new project like this:

[image]

it saves it without workspace (or projects folder) at \Users\{Name}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Project view has an option to compact empty middle packages, enable it. You can also use Flatten packages option. Actually, your question is [a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136625/how-to-change-package-view-in-intellij).
2. IntelliJ IDEA remembers the last location you've used when creating a new project. Once you want to create another project, the location one level upper of the previous project directory would be suggested. So, create a project in `C:\Users\someuser\workspace\myproject1` and IDE will suggest `C:\Users\someuser\workspace\myproject2` for your new `myproject2`.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the cog icon at the top-right of the explorer view, and check the "Flatten packages" option.

[image]

That said, If you get used to keyboard shortcuts top open classes and files, and navigate through recently opened files, you'll quickly see that you'll amost never use the explorer view anymore.